# JSON.parse Unexpected token T in JSON at position 12

Tags: javascript, php, json

Есть у нас сформированный на php масив данных:

```
$data = array(
    '0' => array(
        'TITLE' => '"Title 1"',
        'ID' => 35,
    ),
    '1' => array(
        'TITLE' => '"Тайтл 2"',
        'ID' => 36,
    ),
    '2' => array(
        'TITLE' => '"Тайтл 3"',
        'ID' => 37,
    )
);
```

При попытке перевести его в JS масив путем:

```
var data = $.parseJSON('<? echo json_encode($data); ?>');
```

или

```
var data = JSON.parse('<? echo json_encode($data); ?>');
```

Ловим ошибку: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token T in JSON at position 12
Те выбивает на первом символе на латинице. Если убрать первый элемент с латиницей "Title 1", все работает корректно.

Проверял масив JSON валидаторами все ок, да и у PHP с его обработкой проблем не возникло.
Сам масив:

```
[{"TITLE":"\"Title 1\"","ID":35},{"TITLE":"\"\u0422\u0430\u0439\u0442\u043b 2\"","ID":36},{"TITLE":"\"\u0422\u0430\u0439\u0442\u043b 3\"","ID":37}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`json_encode($data)` возвращает **уже** готовый к работе в JS массив. Поэтому ваш код должен выглядеть так:

```
// не надо ничего парсить и заключать в кавычки
var data = <? echo json_encode($data); ?>;
```